# how to generate array by regular exp in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am a line like:

```
"Advertising"=>,"Arts"=>,"Architecture"=>
```

I like to generate a line like:

```
 "Advertising"=>"Advertising","Arts"=>"Arts","Architecture"=>"Architecture"
```

How can I do this by find and replace using reg exp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the content of double-quotes, and use `$1` backreference for the replacement:

- Search: `("[^"]*")=>`
- Replace: `$1=>$1`